# PHP CURL Script returning an empty array

Tags: php, forms, curl, post

I am just writing to you as I am struggling to get this piece of code to work. I am able to call the api as required from the command line. As soon as I try call it from a php function after converting it to PHP readable curl, it seems to send but I just get an empty array as a response. Its quite confusing as I was getting valid error messages in response from the api previously. I will list the code for both the php and html form.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['testName'];
$email = $_POST['testEmail'];
$file = $_FILES['testFile'];
$url = $_POST['testURL'];

runSend($file, $name, $email);

function runSend($file, $name, $email){

echo "Success, message sent";
        
echo $file;
echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $url;
        
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.boldsign.com/v1/document/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array(
    'Title' => 'Commercial Agreement',
    'Message' => 'Terms, purpose and duration of agreement ',
    'UseTextTags' => 'true',
    'EnableSigningOrder' => 'false',
    'Signers[0][Name]' => 'Example Name',
    'Signers[0][EmailAddress]' => 'example@example.com.au',
    'Signers[0][SignerOrder]' => '0',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][FieldType]' => 'Signature',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Name]' => 'sign_field',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][PageNumber]' => '1',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]' => '50',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]' => '50',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]' => '200',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]' => '30',
    'Signers[0][FormFields][0][IsRequired]' => 'true',
    'Files' => new CURLFILE($file)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: EXAM76242$PLEA32PIK555EY';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

```
<form action="/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/send-test-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        name:
            <input type="text" id="testName" name="testName" value="[7401]"><br>
        email
            <input type="text" id="testEmail" name="testEmail" value="testEmail"><br>
        Select pdf to upload:
            <input type="file" name="testFile" id="testFile">
<input type="text" id="testURL" name="testURL" value="[e2pdf-download id="31" output='url']"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send File" name="submit">
    </form>
```

I have tried refactoring the code numerous times and am frankly stumped.

----------------EDIT/UPDATE-------------------------------------

Hello and thank you. With all your help I am getting closer. Below is my current code and the error that I am getting. If anyone could take another look and see if they can think of any possible causes. Thanks Again!

```
<?php

    if ($_FILES['testFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("File upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['testFile']['error']);
    }

    //$name = $_POST['testName'];
    //$email = $_POST['testEmail'];
    //$url = $_POST['testURL'];
    //fopen($_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    $file = $_FILES['testFile'];

    runSend($file);

    /*
    $location = "/uploads/test/"_.$_FILENAME['testFile']['name']_;
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['testFile']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $location);
    */

    function runSend($file){

        $ch = curl_init();

        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.boldsign.com/v1/document/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $post = array(
            'DisableExpiryAlert' => 'false',
            'ReminderSettings.ReminderDays' => '5',
            'BrandId' => '',
            'ReminderSettings.ReminderCount' => '3',
            'EnableReassign' => 'false',
            'Message' => '',
            'Signers[0][Name]' => 'Enter Name',
            'Signers[0][EmailAddress]' => 'example@example.com.au',
            'Signers[0][SignerOrder]' => '0',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][FieldType]' => 'Signature',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Name]' => 'sign_field',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][PageNumber]' => '1',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]' => '50',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]' => '50',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]' => '200',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]' => '30',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][IsRequired]' => 'true',
            'ExpiryDays' => '30',
            'EnablePrintAndSign' => 'false',
            'AutoDetectFields' => 'false',
            'OnBehalfOf' => '',
            'EnableSigningOrder' => 'false',
            'UseTextTags' => 'true',
            'SendLinkValidTill' => '',
            'Files' => new CURLFILE($file['tmp_name'].'.pdf'),
            'Title' => 'testing',
            'HideDocumentId' => 'false',
            'EnableEmbeddedSigning' => 'false',
            'ExpiryDateType' => 'Days',
            'ReminderSettings.EnableAutoReminder' => 'true',
            'ExpiryValue' => '60',
            'DisableEmails' => 'false'
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        $headers[] = 'X-API-Key: GWAGsagsgaEAWT2545q3AF';
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        
        echo $result;
        
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo $httpcode;
        
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

    };
?>
```

The error message I am currently getting: 0Error:couldn't open file "/tmp/phpWQLlLP.pdf"

Comment: So no errors and result is just empty array? What is the HTTP status code returned?

Comment: What is that `testURL` field needed for, it's not used in your cURL call. Is that your valid APIKey that everyone can use now? How do you check you get an empty array? Nothing in your code.

Comment: An option of the api was to provide FileUrls instead of Files. It did not accept it. Just a remnant of frantically troubleshooting.

Comment: When troubleshooting, I suggest doing it patiently. If you do it frantically, you may find it more difficult.

Comment: haha I know, it was patiently for the first 48hrs. Im getting a 400 http response at the moment. I have a feeling the issue may have something to do with the content-length header. Im not sure how to calculate it dynamically

Comment: This is the current error I am getting.


{"errors":{"":["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-fd88aa221f279b2cab3362e9a3043a58-35d5b59051a18b7a-00"}
I have defined the content-length despite it not being visible in the code above

Comment: After fudging around with configuring this to work without the form I get `"Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"` - once there is a valid certificate it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the end result is expected to be but the following appears to work OK once the curl request is supplied with suitable paramters to deal with the SSL endpoint for the api. In this instance this will print out the example.com page

```
<?php

    function runSend( $url, $file, $name, $email ){
        /*
            Download a valid cacert.pem from 
            https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
            and edit the path below to suit your setup.
        */
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        /*
            supply the various SSL details
        */
        if( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $post = array(
            'Title' => 'Commercial Agreement',
            'Message' => 'Terms, purpose and duration of agreement ',
            'UseTextTags' => 'true',
            'EnableSigningOrder' => 'false',
            'Signers[0][Name]' => 'Example Name',
            'Signers[0][EmailAddress]' => 'example@example.com.au',
            'Signers[0][SignerOrder]' => '0',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][FieldType]' => 'Signature',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Name]' => 'sign_field',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][PageNumber]' => '1',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][X]' => '50',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Y]' => '50',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Width]' => '200',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][Bounds][Height]' => '30',
            'Signers[0][FormFields][0][IsRequired]' => 'true',
            'Files' => new CURLFILE( $file )
        );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: EXAM76242$PLEA32PIK555EY';
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

        $result = curl_exec( $ch );
        if( curl_errno( $ch ) ) echo 'Error:' . curl_error( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        
        return $result;
    }
    
    
    # emulate POST array
    $_POST=array(
        'testName'  =>  'Griselda Grizzleguts',
        'testEmail' =>  'gg@gmail.com',
        'testURL'   =>  'https://example.com'
    );
    
    # configure curl request parameters
    $url='https://api.boldsign.com/v1/document/send';
    $name = $_POST['testName'];
    $email = $_POST['testEmail'];
    $url = $_POST['testURL'];
    $file='c:\temp\ssldebug.txt';
    
    # make the request & print result
    $result=runSend( $url, $file, $name, $email );
    if( $result ){
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($result,true));
    }
?>
```